# Are you supposed to wrap Unit of Work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been *attempting* to educate myself on the whole EF/Repository/Unit of Work architecture- it's going slowly.

Anyway, I've managed to create some repositories and a Unit of Work which use interfaces. (Took me an hour to make it work with interfaces when it was working perfectly without).

Right.. to the question. Is there any point of wrapping the Unit of Work here?

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var all = _unitOfWork.CampaignRepository.All().ToList();
    return View(all);            
}
```

Or

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var uow = _unitOfWork)
    {
        all = uow.CampaignRepository.All().ToList();
        return View(all);
    }
}
```

Also- It is instantiated in the controller

```
public CampaignController(MarketingContext context)
{
    _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
}
```

Does this mean it's **always** available within the controller? Or only when the Unit of Work is specifically called?

Sorry for any naivety, but I've been reading so many different ways of doing everything!

Comment: I usually inject the dependancies through the controller constructor, which makes the code more testable. I also use a IoC container which abstracts the lifetime issues for dependancies, so there is no need to worry about disposing the unit of work.

Comment: if you use ef,it already contains uof and repository.

Comment: @chenZ I have read that EF already does this however I would like to be able to run Unit Tests on my project and repositories and UoW allow this right?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, as you are using entity framework then you don't need to implement UnitOfWork pattern because EF supports for UOF by default.(SaveChanges of EF support UOF)
now if you want to implement the UnitOfWork don't take all of you entities of repository by using ToList(), because you don't need to make operation on your data whenever you call the controller(it's a performance issue), for better implementation of UnotOfWork and Repository pattern take a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/entity-framework-with-repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern-and-poco-architecture) article.

Answer (score 0):

I would never wrap a field inside a using statement because then the field could conceivably be in scope elsewhere, but already disposed. Normally you should instantiate the disposable object within the using clause:

```
   using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
   {
      //etc
   }
```

Override the Dispose method in the controller and call dispose on your UOW there:

```
   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       if (disposing)
           _unitOfWork.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
   }
```

Or you can specify the scope in an IoC container as suggested in the comment by elolos